# when does react apply change on real dom?

Tags: react-virtualized

As we know react works on virtual Dom, not real Dom. When state or props changed،،،،، this change is in the virtual Dom. Can we consider when the call setstate() method this change applies on the real Dom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the setState will trigger a new render on the virtual DOM, which will use its diffing algorithm to check what has changed in the virtual DOM from the last snapshot to the current one.

After that, the virtual DOM will send a "package" with all the needed changes to make.

Finally, the real DOM will update the users' screen.

Comment: thanks...   I am searching  that how  virtual  DOM   send that  package and  I   want to understand this algorithm  and  mechanism  if  you  know  good article  or  reference  about  it  fill    me  in . thanks  again  for your answer .

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+diffing+algorithm+works&ei=m0giYavtCJWw8gKFiJX4Cw try a couple of the first ones